# Run a function after the view (and subviews) finish loading

Tags: android

How do run a function after the view and its subviews have finished loading like in iOS (viewDidAppear / viewDidLayoutSubviews)

I basically want to run a UI animation after the program loads but as my programs too heavy(and has many subviews) the animation doesn't run at all(I tried handler.postDelayed and it worked fine but I wanted to know the more efficient way to do this(for performance reason as a phone I tested on is quite old and takes 4s to load while another takes just a second, etc.).

Comment: Try `view.post(new Runnable())`.

Comment: So there isn't any inbuilt function that runs after all the subviews have finished loading up/rendering?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the ViewTreeObserver for that as stated [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.html#addOnGlobalLayoutListener(android.view.ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener)).
You will have something like:

```
yourView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        // do something here but make sure you unregister if you just want to get notified only once..
    }
});
```

The developers page is stating the following: `Register a callback to be invoked when the global layout state or the visibility of views within the view tree changes`

You can then add this listener on the root view of your activity for example in onCreate and inside that method you can execute your animation.

The method gets called whenever the layout state or the visibility of the view gets changed. It is not like viewDidAppear but it is something similar to "viewDidLayoutSubviews".

You can also try to run the animation in onResume but that will run the animation whenever the activity resumes not only the first time you create it and I am not sure if you want or not that.

Comment: Can you explain what it does in more detail?
Sorry I'm pretty new to android and am having a hard time :)

Comment: Added some more info there, please let me know if you have a specific question :).

Comment: The problem is that my animation starts trying to run before my views finish loading. And as a result the animation doesn't run at all.
I don't understand how i'm supposed to access my view using your suggestion "=_=

Comment: In my example you can see that I added a global layout listener to a view in order to see when the view state changes.. what you have to do is simply replace "yourView" with either the rootView of your Activity or Fragment or the view you target and put the animation code into the callback "onGlobalLayout".